# Simple use of RSACryptoServiceProvider KeyPassword fails

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, public-key

I want to protect my RSA private key with a password (who wouldn't) but the following C# fails:

```
SecureString pw = new SecureString();
pw.AppendChar('x');
CspParameters prms = new CspParameters();
prms.KeyPassword = pw;
RSACryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(prms);
byte[] encrypted = crypto.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("encryptme"), true);
```

...with the CryptographicException: "Invalid type specified". If I take the KeyPassword assignment out it works fine.

What am I, or Microsoft, doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `CspParameters.KeyPassword` is equivalent to calling `CryptSetProvParam` with `PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN` (or `PP_SIGNATURE_PIN`). This flag is not supported by the default Microsoft crypto-service-provider (it is intended for use with smartcard-based CSPs).

You might want to try setting

```
prms.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseUserProtectedKey;
```

or alternatively generating a non-persistent key-pair, exporting it and encrypting it with a key derived from a password yourself.