# How to generate strong-naming SNK key file with .net libraries

Tags: c#, cryptography, strongname, snk

My product needs to be able to generate .snk files (without having Microsoft SDKs installed on the system).
I can generate a working SNK file, but I can not seem to get it to work when specifying a password.
Can anyone give me some pointers?
This is what I have so far:

```
    internal static void CreateKeyPairFile(string fileName, int keySize, string password)
    {
        if ((keySize % 8) != 0)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Invalid key size. Valid size is 384 to 16384 mod 8.  Default 1024.");
        }

        CspParameters parms = new CspParameters();
        parms.KeyNumber = 2;
        if (null != password)
        {
            var passwordString = new System.Security.SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                passwordString.AppendChar(c);
            }
            parms.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseUserProtectedKey;
            parms.KeyPassword = passwordString;
        }
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize, parms);

        byte[] array = provider.ExportCspBlob(!provider.PublicOnly);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When 'password' is not null, "provider.ExportCspBlob" generates the error "invalid type specified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [KeyPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.keynumber.aspx) parameter you use is intended for another purpose than the one you are trying to use it for. From the documentation:

> Use the KeyPassword property to supply a password for a smart card
>   key. When you specify a password using this property, a password
>   dialog will not be presented to the user.

See also the answer to this question: [Simple use of RSACryptoServiceProvider KeyPassword fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915797/simple-use-of-rsacryptoserviceprovider-keypassword-fails)

Besides this, it doesn't seem like you can protect .snk files with a password. What you can do in this case is to use a **PKCS#12** file (.pfx) instead which can be used to sign the assemblies and also can be password protected. You can generate a PKCS#12 file using a library such as [BouncyCastle.NET](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). There is good documentation out there on how to do this, so I won't go into detail here.

See for example: [Is it possible to programmatically generate an X509 certificate using only C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770233/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-generate-an-x509-certificate-using-only-c)